# Need to add 1 word in the result

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I'm creating a webservice which should get data from database(sql server) and return it.
Every thing working fine.But what i need is i need to display the data with the format which i need.

Here is my code:

```
public string GetEmployees()
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NSConstr"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM Contact e ";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
            foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }     

        public string errmsg(Exception ex)
        {
            return "[['ERROR','" + ex.Message + "']]";
        }
```

The result for the above code is:

```
[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"devi","LastName":"priya","Contactno":"965577796 "},{"Id":2,"FirstName":"arun","LastName":"kumar","Contactno":"9944142109"},
{"Id":3,"FirstName":"karu","LastName":"ronald","Contactno":"8883205008"}]
```

What i need is just the word {"cargo": and my result finally }
Here is the result which i expect

```
{ "Cargo": [{"Id":1,"FirstName":"devi","LastName":"priya","Contactno":"965577796 "},{"Id":2,"FirstName":"arun","LastName":"kumar","Contactno":"9944142109"},
{"Id":3,"FirstName":"karu","LastName":"ronald","Contactno":"8883205008"}]}
```

can any one please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `return serializer.Serialize(rows);`
write `return "{ \"Cargo\": " + serializer.Serialize(rows) + "}";`